# Covert stream to image file or PDF file

Tags: php, curl

I'm using Curl to get a file as stream, but I don't know how to save it to a file.
For example, this is the beginning of a stream:

> --------------------------44b53e9274fc6b8c
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="C:\Windows\Temp\php67E3.tmp"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   �����JFIF��x�x�����C�
>   --------------------------44b53e9274fc6b8c--

How can I save this stream as JPEG-file (or in other cases PDF, ...)?

Comment: What is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in `curl_setopt`? And what type of file you are trying to `curl`?

Comment: (From Review:) Please take care that your questions are readable and easily understandable with a clear question statement.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I don't set the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`  , and i would want to convert an image or pdf file.

Comment: That is my Code
`$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setHeader('token', $_SESSION['access_token']);
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
$respon = $curl->get($url);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I'm using this curl Library (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)

Comment: @zx485 Thanks for help